# Sharing GIF from imageView to Whatsapp

Tags: android, bitmap, android-glide, android-bitmap

Trying to share a GIF i loaded into my ImageView into Whatsapp. I can see the GIF animating in my imageview perfectly fine, but it will get this error when I try to share to Whatsapp:-

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gif.GifDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
```

My sharing to Whatsapp method code :-

```java
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) img1.getDrawable();
Bitmap imgBitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
String imgBitmapPath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), imgBitmap, "Whatsapp", null);

Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(imgBitmapPath);

Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgUri);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My Custom Text ");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share this"));
```

My Glide load code:-

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).asGif().load(gifUrl).into(img1);
```

Comment: GifDrawable drawable = (GifDrawable) img1.getGifDrawable(); ?

Comment: A Bitmap cannot contain a Gif.

Comment: Any idea how the code would look like up to the uri parsing for gifDrawable? First time I'm implementing GifDrawable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert GifDrawable to BitmapDrawable.

Get bytebuffer from gifdrawable and save it using bytearray in file. then you can share it using uri. Check below,

**Java**

```
Glide.with(this)
         .asGif()
         .load("your_gif_url")
         .addListener(new RequestListener<GifDrawable>() {
               @Override
               public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {

                   return false;
               }

               @Override
               public boolean onResourceReady(GifDrawable resource, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                   saveImageAndShare(resource);
                   return false;
               }
          }).into(img1);
```

**convert gifdrawable to bytearray and save it file then share it using uri**

```
private void saveImageAndShare(GifDrawable gifDrawable) {
    if (gifDrawable != null) {
        String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        String fileName = "sharingGif.gif";
        File sharingGifFile = new File(baseDir, fileName);
        gifDrawableToFile(gifDrawable, sharingGifFile);
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + ".provider", sharingGifFile);
        this.shareFile(uri);
    }

}

private void shareFile(Uri uri) {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/gif");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Emoji"));
}

private void gifDrawableToFile(GifDrawable gifDrawable, File gifFile) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = gifDrawable.getBuffer();
    try {
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(gifFile);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[byteBuffer.capacity()];
        ((ByteBuffer) byteBuffer.duplicate().clear()).get(bytes);
        output.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Kotlin**

```
Glide.with(this)
                .asGif()
                .load("your_gif_url")
                .addListener(object : RequestListener<GifDrawable> {
                    override fun onLoadFailed(
                        e: GlideException?,
                        model: Any?,
                        target: Target<GifDrawable>?,
                        isFirstResource: Boolean
                    ): Boolean {
                        Log.e("GIF", "GIf failed")
                        return false
                    }

                    override fun onResourceReady(
                        resource: GifDrawable?,
                        model: Any?,
                        target: Target<GifDrawable>?,
                        dataSource: DataSource?,
                        isFirstResource: Boolean
                    ): Boolean {
                        Log.e("GIF", "Test gif done")
                        saveImageAndShare(resource)

                        return false
                    }
                })
                .into(img1)


private fun saveImageAndShare(gifDrawable: GifDrawable?) {

        gifDrawable?.let {

            val baseDir: String = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            val fileName = "sharingGif.gif"

            val sharingGifFile = File(baseDir, fileName)
            gifDrawableToFile(gifDrawable, sharingGifFile)

            val uri: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                sharingGifFile
            )

            shareFile(uri)


        }

    }

    private fun shareFile(uri: Uri) {
        val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        shareIntent.type = "image/gif"

        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Emoji"))
    }

    private fun gifDrawableToFile(gifDrawable: GifDrawable, gifFile: File) {
        val byteBuffer = gifDrawable.buffer
        val output = FileOutputStream(gifFile)
        val bytes = ByteArray(byteBuffer.capacity())
        (byteBuffer.duplicate().clear() as ByteBuffer).get(bytes)
        output.write(bytes, 0, bytes.size)
        output.close()
    }
```

Comment: This is great, but is there any reference in Java for this?

Comment: Hi @Abhay, I just emailed you on this.

Comment: you can post your try here.

Comment: My shareFile method is stored in an on click method under the void onCreate. Before this i put as shareFile() under the onclick method. How do I change it now if using your code?

Comment: you can continue as you are doing 
just type cast to GifDrawable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203661/discussion-between-abhay-koradiya-and-wolfiebae).

Comment: The answer provided here is spot on guys, worked for me

Comment: Ok finally I found the code snippet for gif. can we apply resizing to gif before saving? My code does not change the size of gif. I just want to resizie na with fitCenter and save as gif file rather diplaying on app views